# Video streamed from ffmpeg through Janus is sluttering

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, janus-gateway

I am trying to stream janus, but video is sluttering. My ffmpeg params is

```
 ['-i', '-', '-vcodec', 'copy', '-an','-f', 'rtp', 'rtp://127.0.0.1:5004?pkt_size=1200','-vn', '-acodec', 'copy', '-f', 'rtp', 'rtp://127.0.0.1:5002?pkt_size=1200']
```

(params in nodejs for restream socket packets).

Thank you.

Comment: Try adding `-re` option before the first `-i`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. What does the -re option do?

Comment: It's described in the [`ffmpeg` documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html).